# jQuery target selector attribute with filter value and add new class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I can't find specific post regarding this issue.

Basically, what I'm trying to achieve is to hide the `Compare` text if the `data-product-id` is less than `someValue`

After some searching, this is what I came up with. There is no error but the code just won't do anything. I'm sure my code is wrong.

Can someone explain to me what wrong with my code and it'll be helpful if you guys include/explain the correct way to do it.

```js
$("a[data-product-id]").filter(function() {
    return parseInt($(this).attr("data-product-id")) < 99335;
    $('.show').addClass('hide');
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none !important
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" class="button" data-product-id="99336" rel="nofollow"><p class="show">Compare</p></a>
<a href="#" class="button" data-product-id="99335" rel="nofollow"><p class="show">Compare</p></a>
<a href="#" class="button" data-product-id="99334" rel="nofollow"><p class="show">Compare</p></a>
<a href="#" class="button" data-product-id="99333" rel="nofollow"><p class="show">Compare</p></a>
```

Comment: nothing will execute after `return` statement

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are three problems:

- First, you are calling **[`return`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return)**, and no code after the `return` statement will execute (meaning `$('.show').addClass('hide')` will never get called at all).
- You're not actually running a conditional check on the `data-product-id` value at all; you're simply returning it. Wrap this line in an `if` conditional instead of using `return`.
- Your final problem is that you simply call `$('.show').addClass('hide')`. This will hide **all** of the `.show` elements if **any** of the parents meet the condition. To correct this, you should make use of **[`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/)** with `$(this).find('.show')`.

Here's a working example:

```js
$("a[data-product-id]").filter(function() {
  if (parseInt($(this).attr("data-product-id")) < 99335) {
    $(this).find('.show').addClass('hide');
  }
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none !important
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" class="button" data-product-id="99336" rel="nofollow">
  <p class="show">Compare</p>
</a>
<a href="#" class="button" data-product-id="99335" rel="nofollow">
  <p class="show">Compare</p>
</a>
<a href="#" class="button" data-product-id="99334" rel="nofollow">
  <p class="show">Compare</p>
</a>
<a href="#" class="button" data-product-id="99333" rel="nofollow">
  <p class="show">Compare</p>
</a>
```

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation. I understand it now.

Answer (score 1):

In your function you return the result of your comparison, which exits the function and skips the last part of your code. Instead you want to use a simple `if` to continue execution only when the `data-product-id` is less than `99335`.

Furthermore, if you use `$('.show')`, you would always select all elements with the class `show`. To prevent this, use jQuery's `find()` to limit the selector to child elements only.

```js
$("a[data-product-id]").filter(function() {
    if (parseInt($(this).attr("data-product-id")) < 99335)
        $(this).find('.show').addClass('hide');
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none !important
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" class="button" data-product-id="99336" rel="nofollow"><p class="show">Compare</p></a>
<a href="#" class="button" data-product-id="99335" rel="nofollow"><p class="show">Compare</p></a>
<a href="#" class="button" data-product-id="99334" rel="nofollow"><p class="show">Compare</p></a>
<a href="#" class="button" data-product-id="99333" rel="nofollow"><p class="show">Compare</p></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

There were two problems:

- After return statement, there is no execution of the code.
- Also, you need to catch the current a tag to hide.

Have a look, I have made a demo below

```js
$("a[data-product-id]").filter(function() {
    if( parseInt($(this).attr("data-product-id")) < 99335){
    $(this).removeClass('show').addClass('hide');}
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none !important
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" class="button" data-product-id="99336" rel="nofollow"><p class="show">Compare</p></a>
<a href="#" class="button" data-product-id="99335" rel="nofollow"><p class="show">Compare</p></a>
<a href="#" class="button" data-product-id="99334" rel="nofollow"><p class="show">Compare</p></a>
<a href="#" class="button" data-product-id="99333" rel="nofollow"><p class="show">Compare</p></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a `return` statement which will stop the execution of remaining lines of code in your callback function, use a comparison operator like `if`.

Secondly, only select the children of current element in context using 'children' or 'find' method of jQuery.

There is no need of using !important in CSS.

Hope that solves the issue.

```js
$("a[data-product-id]").filter(function() {
    if(parseInt($(this).attr("data-product-id")) < 99335){
        $(this).children('.show').addClass('hide');
    }
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" class="button" data-product-id="99336" rel="nofollow"><p class="show">Compare</p></a>
<a href="#" class="button" data-product-id="99335" rel="nofollow"><p class="show">Compare</p></a>
<a href="#" class="button" data-product-id="99334" rel="nofollow"><p class="show">Compare</p></a>
<a href="#" class="button" data-product-id="99333" rel="nofollow"><p class="show">Compare</p></a>
```